# How to find same value in same table without hardcoding in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like this:

```
User  | Sale|  Year
-------------------------------
Kim   |  2  |  2019
Kim   |  2  |  2018
Kim   |  1  |  2017
Tim   |  3  |  2019
Tim   |  2  |  2018
Tim   |  1  |  2017
Jim   |  4  |  2019
Jim   |  3  |  2018
Jim   |  3  |  2017
```

There are many records in the table.
I want to add the number of sales in  last years for each user.

Result should be like this:

```
Name | Current Year | Previous Years(Sum)
Kim  |      2       |       3
Tim  |      3       |       3
Jim  |      4       |       6
```

I have tried this so far but no luck

```
select 
User,
Sale as CurrentYearSale,
sum(case when Year < 2019 then cast(Sale as int) end) as PreviousYearsSale
from 
Test 
where Year =2019
group by User,Sale;
```

I cant hardcode the name

Update:

I am getting result like :

```
   User   CurrentYearSale  PreviousYear Sale
  ---------------------------------------------------
    Sam         3                    NULL
    Sam        NULL                  2
    Kim         4                    NULL
    Kim        NULL                   5
    Tim          2                   NULL
    Tim        NULL                    4
```

Comment: Did you try the answers you received?

Comment: Yeah I have tried but not getting the desired result  I have Updated the question with the result of query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try conditional aggregation as shown below-

```
SELECT [User],
SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2019 THEN Sale ELSE 0 END) C_year,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] < 2019 THEN Sale ELSE 0 END) P_year
FROM your_table
GROUP BY  [User]
```

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=89b14a476785eb5a5579414046f4d3ce)

Your given query should be written as below as well-

```
select [User],
sum(case when [Year] = 2019 then cast(Sale as int) ELSE 0 end) as   CurrentYearSale,
sum(case when [Year] < 2019 then cast(Sale as int) ELSE 0 end) as PreviousYearsSale
from Test 
--where Year =2019
-- As your are calculating sum for previous year
-- you do not need to filter data by Year = 2019
group by [User];
```

You can check the output of your query [HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2eff0d10c7e17f760b42e3e0ab68d361)

Comment: I am not getting the desired result , for previous year sales i am getting 3 additional records

Comment: @shah, This should provide you the expected output. Can you please check the db fiddle here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=89b14a476785eb5a5579414046f4d3ce

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select user,
       sum(case when year = 2019 then sales end) as current_year,
       sum(case when year < 2019 then sales end) as previous_years
from dummydata
group by user;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e957e91e54d244c5f0e176428cda2486) is a db<>fiddle.

If you don't want to hardcode the *year*, you can use date functions:

```
select user,
       sum(case when year = year(getdate()) then sales end) as current_year,
       sum(case when year < year(getdate()) then sales end) as previous_years
from dummydata
group by user;
```

Comment: I am getting null values in previous year when Current year is 2019 and getting additional 3 records in those records i am getting previous year sales

Comment: @shah . . . This does exactly what the question is asking for.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation as

```
SELECT UserName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2019 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) CurrYear,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Year < 2019 THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) PrevYears
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('Kim',2, 2019),
  ('Kim',2, 2018),
  ('Kim',1, 2017),
  ('Tim',3, 2019),
  ('Tim',2, 2018),
  ('Tim',1, 2017),
  ('Jim',4, 2019),
  ('Jim',3, 2018),
  ('Jim',3, 2017)
) T(UserName, Sales, Year)
GROUP BY UserName;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
| UserName | CurrYear | PrevYears |
+----------+----------+-----------+
| Jim      |        4 |         6 |
| Kim      |        2 |         3 |
| Tim      |        3 |         3 |
+----------+----------+-----------+
```

**[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=97d7a32fb7abb2f3823e0c8225501c9f)**

Comment: It doesn't work for me when I use my actual table instead of values

Answer (score 0):

you can try something with pivot tables like this

```
  --dummy data
    CREATE TABLE sales 
    (
        "user" varchar(10),
        sales int,
        "year" int,
    )

    drop table sales
    INSERT INTO dbo.sales  VALUES
        ('Kim',2, 2019),
      ('Kim',2, 2018),
      ('Kim',1, 2017),
      ('Tim',3, 2019),
      ('Tim',2, 2018),
      ('Tim',1, 2017),
      ('Jim',4, 2019),
      ('Jim',3, 2018),
      ('Jim',3, 2017)
    ------

    --- query

    select usr , current_year , previous_years
    from 

    (
        select "user" as usr , year,sum(sum_of_sales) as sum_of_sales
        from
        (
            select "user" , 
            case 
                when year = 2019 then 'current_year' 
                when year < 2019 then 'previous_years'
            end as year , 
            sum(sales) as sum_of_sales 
            from sales
            group by "user" , year  
        ) a
        group by "user" ,year


    )  as SourceTable
    pivot 
    (
    sum(sum_of_sales)  
    FOR year IN ( current_year , previous_years)  
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

Result

[image]